# Component state variable as img src url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, grid-layout

I am new to React. I am trying to set the `src` attribute of an image using a component state variable. But when I run the code I don't see the component getting rendered. However if I explicitly define `src` url of the image, it works.

My code is as follows. I am also using React carbon component and react grid layout.

```
import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/styles.scss';
import GridLayout from 'react-grid-layout';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ClickableTile,Link } from 'carbon-components-react';


class ct extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
  super()
  this.state ={
   arr:[]
  }
 }

 componentWillMount(){

   let tilesData = []

   fetch("https://xyz/api/abc")
   .then((results)=>{

      return results.json();

   }).then((data)=>{

        let details = {
            imageUrl:data.images["image"]
        }

        tilesData.push(details)
        this.setState({arr : tilesData})

   })



   render() {

   var layout = [
    {i: 'a', x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 2}
   ];

   return (
   <GridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} rowHeight={30} width={50}>

   <ClickableTile key="a">

    <div>

    // issue here ---------VVVVV
    <img src={this.state.arr[0].imageUrl}/>

    </div>
    </ClickableTile>
   </GridLayout>
  );
  }
 }
```

What could be the issue?

UPDATE - I fixed the issue

FIX - `this.state ={
       arr:[{}]
      }
     }`

Comment: "I" and "am" are separate words, and separately, "I" is always capitalized. :-)

Comment: if api slows down/fails then `this.state.arr[0]` will throw error. Can you post the api result

Comment: the api is working  i have debugged the same , if i remove img src code , it renders properly with other api details .

Comment: nothing wrong with the way your assigning the data to the url, it seems the data must be throwing some sort of error.   The console doesn't have any errors in it?

Comment: If this is the full code you are missing the closing bracket `}` on your `componentWillMount ` function. Should be right after the call to `setState`.

Comment: modified there was a typo.

Comment: Side note (because it's not the main problem): You're falling prey to a common `fetch` mistake, see error #1 in [my blog post here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) -- you need to check for `response.ok`.

Comment: thanks @T.J.Crowder , for the side note incorporate the same in my code .

Answer (score 1):

Your `fetch` operation is asynchronous. You are changing the state without waiting for it to finish. You need to set the state in the `fetch` success callback for the setstate to take effect. Thus, your state is empty because the state was never changed.

Try this:

```
fetch("https://xyz/api/abc")
   .then((results)=>{

      return results.json();

   }).then((data)=>{

        let details = {
            imageUrl:data.images["image"]
        }

        tilesData.push(details)
        this.setState({arr : tilesData}) //call setState in the fetch callback
   })
```

Comment: there was a typo while posting the code here , i have modified the code , please see the updated code .

Comment: You had setState in the callback and it's not setting the state?

Comment: I had setState code in the callback success block also if i do a console.log(this.state.arr) it shows correct results . However if i use the same in img src it doesnt evaluate the state var somehow and the component doesnt load.

Comment: if you inspect that image in devtools, what do you see in the src attribute? is it undefined?

Comment: @Learner2 - `data.images["image"]` is suspect. "images" suggests there's more than one, and `"image"` suggests that the entries may be objects with an `image` property. In which case, you'd want to render all of them (presumably) or at least index into the array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought that part was weird too but OP said he can log the state correctly after setting it, so I was trusting him

Comment: @mxdi9i7 - Yeah. :-| Have to say, I don't buy that the console.log is working but the `img` isn't, unless the `img` isn't getting displayed at all.

Comment: this is just a sample/stripped version of the original code . Also @mxdi917 since img is inside clickable tile component and since the tile component itself doesnt render if i use img having src set to the state var , i think its not possible to  inspect the same in dev tools .

Comment: Could you post the original code here if possible to flush out the confusion?

Answer (score 0):

I  fixed it

```
this.state =
    {
        arr:[{}]
    }
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should [accept it as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) even if [it is your own post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). On the other hand, it would be helpful for future readers if some explanation would be added to the answer.

Comment: if this was the case you should have seen an error in the console that tells you cannot find imageUrl of undefined. But in your question description you stated that there was no error message.

Comment: iam still saying there was no error message also if u assign this.state.arr to src the component renders but if we assign  this.state.arr.imageUrl component doesnt render also no error also thanks for looking into the issue , appreciate ur help on this.